# Code Igniter - Access Forbidden

Tags: php, file-permissions

Please help out, whenever I load codeigniter files on the browser, it keeps saying:

### Acess forbidden!

> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

Comment: Which files? Are you talking about the whole page or a certain folder or file?

Comment: on GNU/Linux(FOR DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT ONLY) : `chmod -R 777 /path/to/project/`

Comment: The 'Welcome to CodeIgniter' File displays properly, as well as all the files in there. As I was doing my first tutorial, the files I was creating as well as the files in that directory wasn't displaying on the broser

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you codeigniter files directory has permission (read and write)